# How to make scale rating bar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

Android have default star rating bar. But in my project have the scale rating bar. how to do like that. Please share your valuable points. Is it possible to do the same way. Below i've pasted sample images. Please give your suggestion. Is any library available for that.

Thanks,

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: looks like a horizontal seekbar to me. you have to look into customizing the color based on the level..

Comment: Its based on click view. user click on 4 means till four have some color, 5 means have some color etc. How can i bring that effect. Please give your idea

Answer (score 0):

Go with custom rating bar . I am posting code that might be helpful to you.

```
   public class CustomRatingBar extends LinearLayout {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context context;
    private RatingHandler ratingHandler;
    private ImageView[] imgStar;

    private int emptyStarResourceId;
    private int starBgColor = 0;
    private int filledStarResourceId;
    private int halfFilledStarResourceId;
    private int starSize;
    private float starRating = 0;
    private boolean isEditable;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public CustomRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomRatingBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        if (attrs == null) {
            filledStarResourceId = R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstar_green;
            emptyStarResourceId = R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstar_gray;
            halfFilledStarResourceId = R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstarhalf_green;
            starRating = 0;
            starSize = convertSizeToDeviceDependent(10);
            isEditable = false;

        } else {
            String namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" + getContext().getPackageName();
            filledStarResourceId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "star_filled", R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstar_green);
            emptyStarResourceId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "star_empty", R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstar_gray);
            halfFilledStarResourceId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, "star_half", R.drawable.ijoomer_ratingstarhalf_green);
            starRating = attrs.getAttributeFloatValue(namespace, "star_rating", 0);
            starSize = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(namespace, "star_size", convertSizeToDeviceDependent(10));
            isEditable = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(namespace, "isEditable", false);
        }
        createView();
    }

    /**
     * This method used to create view.
     */
    private void createView() {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ijoomer_ratingbar, null);
        imgStar = new ImageView[5];
        imgStar[0] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStar1);
        imgStar[1] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStar2);
        imgStar[2] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStar3);
        imgStar[3] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStar4);
        imgStar[4] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStar5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            imgStar[i].setImageResource(emptyStarResourceId);

            imgStar[i].getLayoutParams().width = starSize;
            imgStar[i].getLayoutParams().height = starSize;
            imgStar[i].setTag(i);

            imgStar[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isEditable) {
                        starRating = ((Integer) v.getTag()) + 1;
                        updateView();
                        if (getRatingHandler() != null)
                            ratingHandler.onRatingChangedListener(starRating);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        addView(v, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        updateView();

    }

    /**
     * This method used to update view.
     */
    private void updateView() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            imgStar[i].setImageResource(emptyStarResourceId);
            imgStar[i].getLayoutParams().width = starSize;
            imgStar[i].getLayoutParams().height = starSize;

        }
        if (starRating > 0 && starRating <= 5.0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.ceil(starRating); i++) {
                if (i == Math.floor(starRating) && Math.ceil(starRating) > Math.floor(starRating)) {
                    imgStar[i].setImageResource(halfFilledStarResourceId);
                    if (starBgColor != 0) {
                         imgStar[i].setBackgroundColor(starBgColor);
                    }

                } else {
                    imgStar[i].setImageResource(filledStarResourceId);
                    if (starBgColor != 0) {
                         imgStar[i].setBackgroundColor(starBgColor);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method used to get rating handler.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link RatingHandler}
     */
    public RatingHandler getRatingHandler() {
        return ratingHandler;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get star bg color id.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getStarBgColor() {
        return starBgColor;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set star bg color id.
     * 
     * @param starBgColor
     *            represented bg color id
     */
    public void setStarBgColor(int starBgColor) {
        this.starBgColor = starBgColor;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set rating handler.
     * 
     * @param ratingHandler
     *            represented handler
     */
    public void setRatingHandler(RatingHandler ratingHandler) {
        this.ratingHandler = ratingHandler;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get star size.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getStarSize() {
        return starSize;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set star size.
     * 
     * @param starSize
     *            represented size
     */
    public void setStarSize(int starSize) {
        this.starSize = convertSizeToDeviceDependent(starSize);
        updateView();

    }

    /**
     * This method used to get star rating.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Float}
     */
    public float getStarRating() {
        return starRating;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set star rating.
     * 
     * @param starRating
     */
    public void setStarRating(float starRating) {
        this.starRating = starRating;
        updateView();
    }

    /**
     * This method used to check is editable.
     * 
     * @return represented
     */
    public boolean isEditable() {
        return isEditable;
    }

    /**
     * This method set is editable.
     * 
     * @param isEditable
     *            represented editable
     */
    public void setEditable(boolean isEditable) {
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get empty star resource id.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getEmptyStarResourceId() {
        return emptyStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set empty star resource id.
     * 
     * @param emptyStarResourceId
     *            represented resource id
     */
    public void setEmptyStarResourceId(int emptyStarResourceId) {
        this.emptyStarResourceId = emptyStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get filled star resource id.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getFilledStarResourceId() {
        return filledStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set filled star resource id.
     * 
     * @param filledStarResourceId
     *            represented resource id
     */
    public void setFilledStarResourceId(int filledStarResourceId) {
        this.filledStarResourceId = filledStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get half start resource id.
     * 
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int getHalfFilledStarResourceId() {
        return halfFilledStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set half resource id.
     * 
     * @param halfFilledStarResourceId
     *            represented resource id
     */
    public void setHalfFilledStarResourceId(int halfFilledStarResourceId) {
        this.halfFilledStarResourceId = halfFilledStarResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to convert size to device dependent.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            represented size
     * @return represented {@link Integer}
     */
    public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
    }

    /**
     * Inner interface
     * 
     * @author tasol
     * 
     */
    public interface RatingHandler {
        void onRatingChangedListener(float rating);

    }

}
```